# Select random string in drop down list in c#

Tags: c#, random, names

I am trying to figure out how to have my method randomly select an account type from a drop down list. Basically in my web application the user will choose: active, inactive, prospect, or suspended from a drop down list. What I am trying to do is test this functionality and have my method randomly select a value when I run the test.

I am having a hard time referencing the method to the string value in the code if this makes sense. Any help would be great and if you need additional information let me know!

Here is what I have so far:

```
   public void RandomStatusTypes()
     {
         List<string> statusTypes = new List<string> { "ACTIVE", "INACTIVE", "PROSPECT", "SUSPENDED" };
         Random randStatus = new Random();
         int index = randStatus.Next(0, 6);
         string value = statusTypes[index];
     }
```

The code will have a line saying `StatusTyp = _Status,` and hopefully I can assign a random status to the value so everytime I run the program it randomly picks a value.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have _6_ in _randStatus.Next(...)_? Shouldn't it be _4_?

Comment: @CédricBignon - it must have been 3, not 4, total element are 4 and list had zero-based index

Comment: @CédricBignon, you're right that was typo, thank you!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Can you use `id` of that dropdown in code behind ? ( runat="server" )  Are you using MVC with Razor? More details please.

Comment: @AppDeveloper The second parameter is the _exclusive_ upper bound.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? A test that has randomness in it is very often not a very good idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
private static List<string> StatusTypes = new List<string>(){ "ACTIVE", "INACTIVE", "PROSPECT", "SUSPENDED" };
private static Random randStatus = new Random();

public string RandomStatusTypes()
{
    int index = randStatus.Next(0, StatusTypes.Count);
    return StatusTypes[index];
}
```

Don't create the random instance in the method itself. Otherwise you will create the same statuses when the method is called very fast(f.e. in a loop). You should use a field(as shown above) or pass the random as argument to the method.

I've also moved the list outside of the method since it's ineffective to create it always when it doesn't change anyway. Last i've used `StatusTypes.Count` to ensure that you always use a valid range even if you will change the list in future(f.e. add new statuses).

Comment: Hi Both: Just to let you know there are two errors here. (1). `StatusTypes.Count` should be a `method()` (2). List can go out of range at any time.

Comment: @Kaf: `Count` is a property(not a method) of [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx). It cannot get out of range since I've used the `Count` property for `Random.Next`..

Comment: Ah, okay List<T>. Thanks ! Also, I just checked `lower bound **inclusive**` but `upper bound **exclusive**` which is strange. But you are correct. So I give you a +1 for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in selecting a value from the DropdownList, you should just randomly change the `SelectedIndex` property:

```
 Random randStatus = new Random();
 public void RandomStatusTypes()
 {
          ddlStatus.SelectedIndex = randStatus.Next(ddlStatus.Items.Count);
 }
```

This will randomly change to any value in the dropdown. Notice it uses `ddlStatus.Items.Count` so if you ever add or remove items, you won't have to modify this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need random value for the DropdownList, you should set  the `SelectedIndex` property to a random number

```
   public void RandomStatusTypes()
     {
         List<string> statusTypes = new List<string> { "ACTIVE", "INACTIVE", "PROSPECT", "SUSPENDED" };
         Random randStatus = new Random();
         dropList.Items.AddRange(statusTypes);
         dropList.SelectedIndex = randStatus.Next(0, 3);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `function` which `returns a random item` from the passing `myList`

```
public string RandomListItem(List<string> myList)
{
    int randNo = new Random().Next(0, myList.Count());
    return myList[randNo];
}
```

Comment: would I have to include the whole list of names when referencing those values in the method?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to return an index from that method ( void = it returns nothing ) to use as a `selected value` for your `DropDownList`.

```
public int RandomStatusTypes()
 {
     List<string> statusTypes = new List<string> { "ACTIVE", "INACTIVE", "PROSPECT", "SUSPENDED" };
     Random randStatus = new Random();
     return randStatus.Next(0, statusTypes.Count);
 }
```

After that you can call that method somewhere like this

```
  var statusForDropDown= RandomStatusTypes();
```

And assign `statusForDropDown` to your `DropDownList`

```
     MyDropDownList.SelectedIndex=statusForDropDown;
```